# JMeter BeanShell PreProcessor

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I would like to generate a random letter and assign it to a variable, then append it to the request. However, my current script is not functioning as expected. Could you assist me in identifying what might be incorrect?

```
import java.util.Random;

char getRandomLowercaseLetter() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    char randomLetter = (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a'); // Generating a random lowercase letter
    return randomLetter;
}

// Get the current value of the randomInput variable
String currentRandomInput = vars.get("randomInput");

// Generate a random lowercase letter
char randomLetter = getRandomLowercaseLetter();

// Set the random letter as the new value for the randomInput variable
vars.put("randomInput", currentRandomInput + randomLetter);

// Logging the new value of randomInput
log.info("New randomInput value: " + vars.get("randomInput"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's recommended to use built-in JMeter functionality and avoid scripting where possible. Your requirement can be implemented using [__RandomString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) like:

   ```
   ${__RandomString(1,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
   ```

   and this function can be used anywhere in your script
2. If you prefer to do it in the code you can call [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphabetic-int-) function

   ```
   vars.put("randomInput", org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(1).toLowerCase());
   ```
3. And last but not the least, using Beanshell is some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so consider migrating. More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)